# iOS Touch to return to call

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have one question how to create "Touch to return to call" which is showing green banner when call screen runs background. Are there any possibilities to create our own Green color banner when application background?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately not. You cannot create your own custom banner control in this fashion.

Those banners (red for active mic, blue for location, green for call) are all system spawned.

Answer (score 0):

As Woodstock's answer there is no way for this. But maybe you may send periodic local notifications to user like "we are working here" etc. This is not what you want but maybe this could be another approach to inform user.